# react-native-mapbox-gl vs react-native-maps in 2021

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mapbox, react-native-maps

I'm looking to build an app using React Native (expo) that needs to render a map. After looking around a bit, it looks like `react-native-maps` and the unofficial MapBox RN library are the two main options. I tried looking around for some comparisons between the two, but couldn't find any updated information.

How do the two compare in terms of performance and customizability? These are the two that I'm most concerned about. Mostly, I'm interested in rendering a lot of markers, potentially making use of clustering, and customizing the map and marker styles.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also interested in know this. I started integrating react-native-maps since it's _by far_ the more popular solution, but I am interested in using Mapbox, since their prices are significantly cheaper than GoogleMaps. Do you know if it's possible to use Mapbox as the maps provider for react-native-maps?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on both. From my experience for basic funtionality react native map can be used but for advance and heavy map use mapbox will be suitable. My requirements was showing multiple markers with feature of updating it on press also showing polygons of region at same time. This was achieved using mapbox only as the react native map crashing or the app was freezing very often on latest devices also.
Secondly react native mapbox api's are also cheaper than of google maps.